# Review tab being removed after product view xml override

Tags: xml, magento2

I am having an issue where the review tab on my theme is removed when I override the "product.info.details" block in the catalog_product_view.xml

Im just trying to add 2 new tabs for product details and delivery information. These two work perfectly and appear where i want them to but the reviews tab is now missing.

this is my catalog_product_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/> 
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.main.content" after="product.info.media"/> 
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="product.main.content" before="-"/> 
        <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.main"/>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" as="description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.productdetails" as="productdetails" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_details.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.description">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">30</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.deliveryinfo" as="deliveryinfo" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.description">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Delivery Information</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">40</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-main-content" before="-">
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        
    </body>
</page>
```

And this is the result on the page:
[image: product page]

Is there something i am missing from the xml, if i remove the override and use base Magento code it appears back where it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the solution. and it was just me not being observant enough. I needed to put the product.info.details block into the container i made for it...

in case anyone is interested this is what it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/> 
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.main.content" after="product.info.media"/> 
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="product.main.content" before="-"/> 
        <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.main"/>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-main-content" before="-">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" as="description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                            <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                            <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.productdetails" as="productdetails" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_details.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.description">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
                            <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.deliveryinfo" as="deliveryinfo" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.description">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Delivery Information</argument>
                            <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        
    </body>
</page>
```